# Styling nested items in css with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, nested

I'm trying to figure out how styling nested items works, as well as how to access each item every time. 
What I'd like to do(at least to get the styling going) is change both of the Navbars background-color, but am unsure what exactly I need to target in my css.

Any help would be appreciated.

Below is my Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Footer-navbar</title>

    <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="footer-navbar.css">

</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: There seems to be only 1 navbar, and don't use `.bg-*` classes if you need to add your own background.

Comment: you can write custom CSS, instead of always focus on classes.

Comment: I've added one because the other one's the same except for it's fixed bottom. :) @AnuragSrivastava

I tried removing the .bg and that helped. Tnx! :)